# Debug log file with rolling datestamp in filename?

Tags: logging

We currently have this config for our logging in our wordpress wp-config.php file

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
@ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
@ini_set( 'log_errors', 1 );
@ini_set( 'error_log', dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-content/debug.log' );
```

I'm wondering is there a way to get wordpress to create a distinct log file per day. In java land and log4j, there is a RollingDailyFileLogger which renames the log file at mid-night.

Is there any package or library which would allow be to define the wordpress debug file in this format

```
@ini_set( 'error_log', dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-content/${YYYY-MM-DD}-debug.log' );
```

Thanks

EDIT - I have one idea to setup a wordpress cron job which would be scheduled to run at midnight. The job would rename the existing 'debug.log' file with the previous dates daystamp and assume the error_log() would recreate the file. Not the nicest but it might work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, yes - there is such way. And you even have the solution already in your code...

Even more - you almost solved it yourself...

This line decides, where the log will be located:

```
@ini_set( 'error_log', dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-content/debug.log' );
```

So all you need is to add date in that file name. Like this:

```
@ini_set( 'error_log', dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-content/' . date('Y-m-d') . '-debug.log' );
```

As you can see no cron is needed to achieve this ;)